# R Writing list of lists (.txt) with spaces between them in R

Tags: r, list, dataframe

Suppose I have a list of lists in R, for example:

list 1 contains 10 pairs of coordinates (x,y)

list 2 contains 20 pairs of coordinates (x,y)

...

list 20 contains 10 pairs of coordinates (x,y)

I would like to write an output (.txt) file with those lists. At the end of each list I'd like to add an blank line to separate them.

I already know that

p2 = as.data.frame(do.call(rbind,p)), if p is my list of lists

will change to a data-frame.

Then write.table(p2,file="forest",row.names=FALSE) will print every list but without the spaces. Can someone help me? Does "cat" can be used here, like cat(" ",p)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please add something that you tried and edit your question with proper formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're definitely on the right track with cat(). Below I create a list of lists (of varying sizes). I then loop through each one to write it to a text file after converting each list to a data.frame class object. After each write.table() call, I use cat() to enter a space ("\n").

This could should run on your end (might get a warning message saying that it is printing column names - don't worry about this...the txt file will still generate) and will output a txt file called test.txt to your working directory (getwd()).

```
exp_list<-list(list(x=rnorm(10,500,10),y=rnorm(10,500,10)),
               list(x=rnorm(20,500,10),y=rnorm(20,500,10)),
               list(x=rnorm(20,500,10),y=rnorm(20,500,10)))

for(i in 1:length(exp_list)){
  write.table(data.frame(exp_list[[i]]),file='test.txt',append=TRUE, row.names=FALSE)
  cat('\n',file='test.txt',append = TRUE)  
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Using the sample data from Arman

```
library(dplyr)

exp_list<-list(list(x=rnorm(10,500,10),y=rnorm(10,500,10)),
               list(x=rnorm(20,500,10),y=rnorm(20,500,10)),
               list(x=rnorm(20,500,10),y=rnorm(20,500,10)))

exp_list %>%
  lapply(as.data.frame) %>%
  bind_rows(.id = "ID") %>%
  mutate(ID = as.numeric(ID) ) %>%
  write.table(sep = " ", row.names = FALSE)
```

Comment: This doesn't actually output a txt file in the working directory and therefore doesn't answer OP's question. Furthermore, when you set the write.table file= parameter to "testfile.txt", it DOES create a txt file, but the data frames are not separated by a blank line.